# Update value in hash of hashes in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I'm a **very** beginner in Perl. I have an hash `$self` which contains other hashes, in particular it contains an hash with the key `params`. I want to update the value correspondent to the key `color` of `params`, from `black` to `white`. 
In other words, how `$self` is:

```
{
    'params' => {
        'color' => 'black',
        #other keys/values here...
     },
    #other hashes here...
};
```

What I want:

```
{
    'params' => {
        'color' => 'white',
        #other keys/values here...
     },
    #other hashes here...
};
```

What I tried:

```
sub updatePrice {
    my ($self, $text) = @_; # I can't change this
    my %params = %{$self->{params}};
    $params{color} = 'white'; 
    print Data::Dumper::Dumper{$params{color}};
    # ...
}
```

But I get a `Odd number of elements in anonymous hash` warning, while the printing is `$VAR1 = { 'white' => undef };`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should alter the line marked `# I can't change this` to `my $self = shift;` and `my ($text) = @_;` That is very common practice, and leaves the explicit parameters to the subroutine in `@_` but removes the object or class receiving the message which should be *read-only*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your *error* is caused because you've got too many `{` in your `Data::Dumper` line.

`{}` is also an anonymous hash constructor, so you can:

```
my $hashref = { 'key' => 'value' };
```

That's sort of what you're doing before passing it to `Data::Dumper` only you're only supplying one value - which is why you get the "odd number of elements" warning. (And a hash of `{ 'white' }` isn't what you're trying to achieve anyway)

Try:

```
print Data::Dumper::Dumper  $params{color};
```

Or just:

```
print Data::Dumper::Dumper \%params;
```

But also - you're probably doing this the wrong way - `%params` is a copy of the tree from `$self`, so updating it doesn't change the original.

```
my %params = %{$self->{params}};
```

creates a copy.

You probably want:

```
$self -> {params} -> {color} = "white"; 
print Dumper $self;
```

It's probably worth noting - `$self` is typically used to reference an *object*, and it may get confusing if you use it for a "normal" hash.